# Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python

What do these two statements mean in Python?

```
distances[(clust[i].id,clust[j].id)]=distance(clust[i].vec,clust[j].vec)

d=distances[(clust[i].id,clust[j].id)]
```

I am guessing that the first statement assigns `clust[i].id` and `clust[j].id` keys of the distances map to the result of the `distance(..)` function. However, I am confused since lists are represented using `[]` and dictionaries using `{}` in Python. What's the correct answer?

Comment: "However, I am confused since lists are represented using [ ] and dictionaries using { } in Python.".  What?  The `[]` is for getting an item, not representing a list.  What makes you think it has anything to do with lists?

Comment: Also note that `anything[(a, b)]` can be written as `anything[a, b]`, just like you can do `for x, y in z:` and `for x in y, z:` without needing the parentheses.

Comment: @S. Lott. Is this your way of helping people who have less factual knowledge about a particular programming language than you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
distances[(clust[i].id,clust[j].id)]=distance(clust[i].vec,clust[j].vec)
```

`distances` is a dictionary where **keys** are **tuples** of *probably* integers and the **value** is the distance measured between them by the `distance` function.
in the second line:

```
d=distances[(clust[i].id,clust[j].id)]
```

the `d` variable is just assigned to that distance, accessing the dictionary value just assigned.
other answers provide the summary of what's a dictionary.

Answer (score 6):

Dictionary *literals* use `{}`. Indexing operations use `[]`, regardless of type.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this will make it clear:

```
>>> a = {}
>>> a[1] = 2
>>> a[(1, 2)] = 3
>>> a
{(1, 2): 3, 1: 2}
```